# Making a Sphere Jump

Tags: unity, c#, movement, jumping

I'm making a very simple game with a sphere that's supposed to roll and bounce on "planets". **Also, please be ready to read a lot. I want to be very descriptive for you.** :)

I've pretty-much-done everything for the game already, except I have a problem with jumping. When I press the space bar, the sphere will hop once. But after pressing space again, it will not.

## What We're Dealing With

Now this sounds like an easy fix, but keep in mind that the player object was designed with the mesh (rendered) `Player_Ball`, and the jump collider named `Player_JumpBox`, which is just an invisible collider smaller than `Player_Ball`. My idea was that when an object with a "static" tag is the object the `Player_JumpBox` collides with (which is a trigger), it will enable the user to jump. So this meant I had to make two different classes. One for the parent object, that holds both `Player_Ball` and `Player_JumpBox`, and one for the `Player_JumpBox` titled "JumpControl.cs", so it could handle the `Player_JumpBox` `OnTriggerEnter` event.

[image: The player ball.]

The `JumpControl.cs` file located on the `Player_JumpBox` object, takes input from the user, and controls when to jump. (Note: I did not say how to jump)

The `PlayerController.cs` file located on the parent `Player` object, controls everything about the player. It controls how to jump. (Basically has variables like `jumpForce` and a function that `JumpControl.cs` uses to tell the parent object to jump.)

[image: The PlayerController.cs file for the Player object.]

## The Scripts (C#)

`JumpControl.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class JumpControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;   // The parent object, holding both 

    private bool canJump;

    void Start () {
        canJump = true;
    }

    // Every physics update, check if the user is pressing `space', and if so, jump, then set 'canJump = false'.
    void Update () {
        if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis("Jump")) > 0.1 && canJump == true) {
            player.GetComponent<PlayerController> ().Jump ();
            canJump = false;
            print ("DEBUG: canJump = " + canJump);
        }
    }

    // When the user nears the ground, enable them to jump again.
    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider c) {
        if (c.CompareTag("Static")) {
            canJump = true;
            print ("DEBUG: canJump = " + canJump);
        }
    }
}
```

`PlayerController.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;                 // The player's rolling speed.
    public int maxCoins;                // The number of coins in the level.
    public Text counter;                // The text that displays the number of coins the player has.
    public Text finalText;              // The text that displays win-text.
    public bool isTutorial;             // Whether or not this is a tutorial.
    public float jumpForce;             // The force of jumping.

    private Rigidbody rb;               // The rigidbody.
    private float moveVertical;
    private float moveHorizontal;
    private int coins;                  // Number of coins the player has.

    void Start () {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        coins = 0;
        UpdatePoints ();
        finalText.text = "";
    }

    void Update() {
        moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c) {
        if (c.gameObject.CompareTag ("Coin")) {
            c.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            coins++;
            UpdatePoints ();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates points the user has, and displays them on the screen.
    /// </summary>
    void UpdatePoints() {
        if (coins < maxCoins) {
            counter.text = "Coins: " + coins;
        } else {
            counter.text = "Coins: " + coins;
            if (isTutorial) {
                finalText.text = "Tutorial complete!";
            } else {
                finalText.text = "You win!";
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The method JumpControl.cs uses to make the player jump.
    /// </summary>
    public void Jump() {
        Vector3 jump = new Vector3 (0.0f, jumpForce);
        rb.AddForce (jump);
        print ("Jumped");
    }
}
```

(The only truly important thing is the `Jump` method at the bottom of `PlayerController.cs`)

## What I Want

I really just want to know why the player isn't bouncing everytime I press 'space'. It's really bam-boozled me for a while, and I really need your help.

Thanks for reading! I tried to make it easy to understand.

Comment: For those of the people that want to see what I mean in action, view [this link](https://gyazo.com/5c597bfa938c3b452cb66e3b8e0c45df). I'm attempting to jump to the last planet, but I am unable to do so. (Note: The log is at the bottom of the screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, I assumed I already made the `Player`'s Rigidbody a trigger.

Also, you need to make each and every child of the planet (like the tops of the planet) that you want to let the player bounce on to be **static**; not just the empty object parent.

I'm very sorry I never double-checked, but I hope this helps others out.

Comment: Might be worth marking your question as answered, just to avoid confusion :)

Comment: @hobnob I can't, because I need to accept it tomorrow. lol, I would have.

Comment: It's now a little bit past tomorrow. Could you accept this now, @VenHayz?